# Database.ExecuteSqlCommand returns incorrect rowcount

Tags: entity-framework-6, dml

I'm using context.Database.ExecuteSql to update a table. The update with where clause is executed correctly and the record is updated. However the method returns 2 for rowcount instead of 1. When I execute the update statement in SSMS, the result rowcount returned is 1. Can someone provide insight on this?

```
            string query =
            string.Format("update {0} set Description = '{1}', Code = '{2}', LastUpdatedBy = '{3}', LastUpdatedDate = '{4}' where ID = {5};",
                tableName,
                description,
                code,
                lastUpdatedBy,
                lastUpdatedDate,
                ID);

        int rowCount = 0;
        string message = string.Empty;

        using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
        {
            rowCount = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction, query);
        }

        return rowCount == 0 ?  //this return 2 instead of 1.
            new SaveResult(SaveResult.MessageType.Error, string.Format("There was an error updating a record in the {0} table.", tableName), "Index") :
            new SaveResult(SaveResult.MessageType.Success, string.Format("The update of {0} was successful.", tableName), "Index");
```

This returns rowcount = 1 in SSMS:

```
update zAddressTypes 
set Description = 'Current', Code = '101122', LastUpdatedBy = 'user', LastUpdatedDate = '10/20/2014 12:17:26 PM' 
where ID = 1; 

DECLARE @RowCount INTEGER = @@ROWCOUNT; 
select @RowCount;
```

Answer (score 2):

The rowcount is being returned separately. What you are seeing here is the exit status of the query.

`ExecuteSqlCommand` return value is for the status of query not for row count. You may want to look into using a datareader or something similar to return the rowcount.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it.

Comment: This is incorrect. Check the MS docs. The return value is "The result returned by the database after executing the command" as stated in the MS docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Answer (score 1):

It is the way the datacontext works, see this link:
[Entity Framework: Database.ExecuteSqlCommand Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276996/entity-framework-database-executesqlcommand-method)
Apparently the command is updating two records.

Comment: Rows updated as a result of triggers are also included in the affected row count.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a trigger on your table? I confirmed this behavior can be caused by a trigger as the rows affected by the trigger are added to the row count affected by your SQL command. I commonly check for a 0 or >0 return value to know if anything was affected. You could also return an output variable if you're calling a stored procedure.